# AVFragmentedAssetMinder not working on iPhone device but works on simulator

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

We have fragmented movie data that comes through WebSecureSocket (wss://). We are writing that into a **temp.mp4** and simultaneously playing the fragments that got written into the file. So, we used **AVFragmentedAsset** and **AVFragmentedAssetMinder** for this. It works as expected in the simulator. But in the device, doesn't update the duration of the asset and doesn't post the **.AVAssetDurationDidChange** notification. Not sure what could be the issue. Already spent 2 days figuring out this but no luck. Can someone help me with this please,

Implementation..

```swift
public class WssPlayerSource: WebSocketDelegate {
    
    static let ASSET_MINDER = AVFragmentedAssetMinder()
    
    private let socketClient: WebSocketStreamingClient
    private var tempMovieFile:FileHandle? = nil
    private var startedPlay = false
    private var fragmentedAsset: AVFragmentedAsset? = nil
    
    let player = AVPlayer()
    
    init(withUrl url: URL) {
        socketClient = WebSocketStreamingClient(wssUrl: url)
        socketClient.delegate = self
        do {
            self.tempMovieFile = try getTemporaryMovieFileWriter()
        }catch {
            print("Error opening file")
        }
        
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(onVideoUpdate), name: .AVAssetDurationDidChange, object: nil)
        socketClient.connect()
    }
    
    // Socket delegate
    public func didReceive(event: WebSocketEvent, client: WebSocket) {
        switch event {
        case .binary(let data):
            
            self.tempMovieFile?.write(data)
           
            if !startedPlay {
                startedPlay = true
                DispatchQueue.global().async { [weak self] in
                    self?.didReceivedInitialData()
                }
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
    
    func didReceivedInitialData() {
        fragmentedAsset = AVFragmentedAsset(url: getTemporaryMovieFile()!)
        fragmentedAsset?.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: ["duration", "containsFragments", "canContainFragments"], completionHandler: {
            WssPlayerSource.ASSET_MINDER.mindingInterval = 1
            WssPlayerSource.ASSET_MINDER.addFragmentedAsset(self.fragmentedAsset!)
            
            self.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: AVPlayerItem(asset: self.fragmentedAsset!))
            self.player.play()
        })
    }
    
    @objc
    func onVideoUpdate() {
        print("Video duration updated..")
        // This is not called in device.. but in simulator it works as expected
    }
    
    func stop() {
        socketClient.forceDisconnect()
        NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
        if let asset = self.fragmentedAsset {
            WssPlayerSource.ASSET_MINDER.addFragmentedAsset(asset)
        }
    }
}
```

And

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var playerView:PlayerView!
    
    private static let SOCKET_URL = "wss://..."
    
    private var playerSource:WssPlayerSource? = nil
    private var playerLayer:AVPlayerLayer? = nil
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.playerSource =  WssPlayerSource(withUrl: URL(string: ViewController.SOCKET_URL)!)
        self.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: self.playerSource!.player)
        self.playerLayer?.videoGravity = .resize
        self.playerView.layer.addSublayer(self.playerLayer!)
    }
}
```

Comment: Show how a PlayerController instance is created and maintained. How do we know it doesn't go out of existence before notifications can arrive? Looks to me like it might be a weak reference. (Plus the use of `sleep(2)` is highly suspect.)

Comment: @matt Thank you for looking into this.  For sake of readability, I wrapped the code inside `PlayerController` for this post. This is created and managed in ViewController.  `sleep(2)` is not a problem, I just added it so more data would be available in the file before Asset is initialized.

Comment: So this isn't your real code?

Comment: @matt It was real code. Just that I posted the required part.  Now, I have updated with full code. Please have a look